# class create object with initialization trick

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I have program on phone book. With the first class

```
class entry
{
  string name;
  int number;
   ...
}
```

With the 2nd class handling array of objects

```
   class phoneBook
{
   Entry objs[100];//maximum 100 users
   //getter and setter below
   ...
}
```

I have main() function to control them.

```
int main(){
    phoneBook p;
    p.count(count);
    p.add(count,name,number);
    p.print();
     ...
}
```

My questions is with the line:

```
 phoneBook p;
```

Each time I call this line, it will initialize the `objs[100]` in class `phoneBook`. Suppose I am imputing objs[2], my objs[1] will be empty then. How to fix my structure please?

Comment: I very often say that: `int` is **not** the right type for telephone numbers. Telephone numbers are *strings* of digits, not integer numbers. For example, in many parts of the world, most telephone numbers start with 0.

Comment: Other than that, your question is too broad. Read the next few chapters in the book or website that you use to learn C++, they will point you to the right data structures. We can't explain that here, because your question indicates that we would have to write that book to explain this to you, sorry.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure exactly what you're asking but every time you call `phoneBook p;` you are creating a new _empty_ phone book. Are you creating a new phone book every time you add an entry?

Comment: Hi,Gary. Thanks for your reply. Yeah, you see the point. Every time, I call phonebook p, I create a new phonebook. But I want to avoid to create a new one, but I dont't know how. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to read some introductory C++/object oriented tutorials. I think the answer to that is outside the scope of what we can provide here... Object oriented programming can be weird at first but you'll catch on :)

Comment: Thanks gary. I am newbee and trying to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `phoneBook` class should only allocate space, if necessary.  Since you have no idea the content of an entry, at initialization, setting entry values makes no sense.

I highly recommend that you use a more dynamic structure than an array, such as `std::vector`, `std::list` or `std::map`.

Your `phoneBook` class needs methods to *append, or insert or read` new entries.  This will allow you to fill in the allocated spaces with reasonable data.

If you are using an array for the entries, there is only space allocated for the entries.  The `append` method would initially place a new entry at `objs[0]`.  The next entry at `objs[1]` and so on.

Also, search StackOverflow or the web for "c++ phone book example" which should yield a bunch of examples for you to ponder.  Remember, search first before posting here.  Or debug first before posting here.